# Why gedit and some other apps under Mate do not follow the desktop theme?

Tags: theme, mate-desktop

I am currently using a theme based on Green Laguna (actually, Green Laguna itself, but MATE Desktop Environment 1.18.0 thinks something was customized).

[image]

`Caja` and many other apps follow the theme style:

[image]

But `Gedit` and some other apps do not:

[image]

What is required to apply theme to all apps?

Comment: I understand and do not dispute your right to vent frustration at someone who does not share your enthusiasm about perpetual upgrading of Linux by downvoting this post, but remember that silencing criticism does not make Linux any better. It only encourages destructive habits of not testing and breaking backwards compatibility by developers and distro builders. You are, metaphorically, digging your own grave by throwing rocks at me.

Comment: Downvotes aren’t about silencing criticism, they mean that “This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)” (as per the tooltip).

Comment: This is highly subjective, and just not true.

Comment: GTK3 disobeys theming of all environments, not just Mate. And I had no way of knowing, other than by asking the question, or reverse-engineering the `gedit` code. So in sum, you are denying that asking questions and getting answers is the stated puropose of this resource. You are making zero sense. I had enough and not going to further this. Apparently you believe it is perfectly valid that some come to this resource with a mindset locked on "I am looking at this question and determining that it is not helpful to the rest of 7 billion people on Earth, so this is a bad question". Rich!

Comment: You’re reading too much into all your interactions here. What I’m saying is that downvotes are more likely to indicate that people thought your question showed a lack of research, rather than be evidence of people trying to silence your criticism (and since your question doesn’t seem to me to be critical anyway, I’m not sure why you would think that in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

gtk2 vs. gtk3. Caja uses gtk2 and your gtk2 theme, while gedit is based on gtk3.
If you wanna bring back your old gtk2 title bar with gtk3, then use [nocsd](https://github.com/PCMan/gtk3-nocsd). And choose a theme which also supports gtk3 as gtk2 as well. (There are very few of them.)

[image: nocsd]
[image: csd]

Comment: @ajeh that’s rather extreme. As always it’s a case of resources and priorities; if you care about it that much, you are welcome to put your skills, time, and/or money where your mouth is.

Comment: Braking backwards compatibility seems to be a priority of the day. Everyone insists on doing that, and the rest on justifying that. I wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

We are already fighting an uphill battle to keep Gnome2 style desktop by using Mate, and GTK3 invading the system and disobeying the global theme is extremely annoying and very unwelcome.

The first step is to remove `gedit`:

```
sudo dnf remove gedit -y
```

The second it to install `pluma`:

```
sudo dnf install pluma -y
```

But if we still want to continue using `gedit` on the command line, as we used to, and do not want to learn another command, we can download [the last GTK2 version of gedit](http://rpmfind.net/linux/Mandriva/official/2011/x86_64/media/main/release/gedit-2.30.4-3-mdv2011.0.x86_64.rpm), open it with any suitable archive manager (I use `mc`), then open `CONTENTS.cpio` and copy `etc` and `usr` to the root folder.

That automatically adds the main menu entry for `gedit` in Mate as well.